# Как я могу получить всевозможные комбинации списка без повторений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Я импортирую модуль itertoools и применяю его на списке [1, 2, 3] следующим образом:
`itertools.combinations(lst, len(lst))`
Но в ответ я получаю исходный список и более ничего.
А хочу увидеть

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Как я могу получить все комбинации длиной со список? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что вам нужны [перестановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) :), а не [сочетания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

```
import itertools

variants = list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3], 3))
print(*variants, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

С другой стороны если вам понадобятся когда-нибудь все возможные комбинации, это тоже нетрудно сделать с помощью того же модуля :)

```
import itertools
variants = list(itertools.product(*[lst] * 3))
print(*variants, sep='\n')
```